# javascript basic collision function for high school project

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi everyone I'm trying to make a collision function, so if the monkey touches the banana the banana moves to somewhere around the canvas.

Currently monkey and the coconut are moving around and the monkey and banana collide, but the banana doesn't move afterwards.

This is the function:

```
var mx = canvas.width / 2;     
var my = canvas.height / 2;
var mdx = 0;        
var mdy = 0;
var mspeed = 2;        
var mlives = 3; 
var cx = 400;
var cy = 250;
var cspeed = 3;
var cdx = cspeed - 1;
var cdy = cspeed;
var bx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
var by = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
var bananasEaten = 0;
var lives = 3;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

function getBanana() {
    if (mx <= (bx + bananaImage.width) && bx <= (mx + monkeyImage.width)) {
        if (my <= (by + bananaImage.height) && by <= (my + monkeyImage.height)) {
             bananasEaten = bananasEaten + 1;
             bx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - bananaImage.width));
             by = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - bananaImage.height));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be clear about what you're asking. What is the desired output, and what, if anything, isn't working for you currently?

Comment: The monkey is currently moving around and the coconut moves around but the monkey and banana collide but the banana doesn't move afterwards,

Comment: To increase the chance to get an answer you should avoid to write your question to chatty, and you should include all important information within the question. (What does currently work in your code, and what does not work and if you already have an idea why this is the case, then add the information too) I updated your question accordingly.

Comment: Might be relevant for your question: [collision detection algorithm issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788395/collision-detection-algorithm-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically you'd like to check if the position of the monkey(mx, my) match the position of the banana(bx, by). Therefore:

```
 if( mx + monkey.width >= bx && mx <= bx + banana.width &&
     my + monkey.height >= by && my <= by + banana.height) {
      // Execute code
 }
```

Although, I should mention that you probably need to put this `getBanana` function inside another function that draws the game, which is being called again and again either with `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`, since I'm guessing this is some game.